# Error caused by total_likes in Function Django

Tags: python, django

I have been able to add a like button which is working but when I add total_likes context everything doesn't work.

The total_likes have been hashtagged/commented in the LikeView.

The count is working perfectly in the admin and with every like it is added to the count because in the Post Detail View it is recognized, it is only not working in the LikeView.

I want to know why the hashtagged/commented part is wrong and how to resolve it.

Here is the views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context

def LikeView(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    # stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    # total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    context = {
        # 'total_likes': total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post
    }

    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Here is the '''models.py'''

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ----------
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='liked')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: To start with, it's a function based view, so doesn't have `self`...

Comment: @thebjorn I didn't understand your comment could explain.. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but explaining the difference between a method in a class and a function (and why one of them has self) is beyond the scope for the comment section...